# JS that reads an XML file, writes HTML code for several divs, then repeats itself until it gets to the end of the list

Tags: javascript, html

I’d like to update the following page so that it’s easier to maintain. http://jsfiddle.net/johanbak/129uq4ts/5/ (**Tip:** There are panels that contain up to nine squares. Click the gray bars on the left or right to get to the next panel.)

Currently, if I want to add a form, I have to update the HTML and that gets messy. Instead I’d like to maintain an XML file that lists all of my forms. The HTML file would contain a script that writes the HTML code for me based on the contents of the XML.

The HTML has a main div (called panel_wrap). The panel_wrap div contains previous/next navigation divs, and nine square divs (called square). I’d like the javascript to do the following:

1. Create a panel_wrap div
2. Populate the panel_wrap div with the previous/next divs. (I don't mind having to update these independently.)
3. Populate the panel_wrap div with nine squares (items 1 through 9 in the XML file).
4. Create a new panel_wrap div with a unique id.
5. Repeat step 2.
6. Repeat step 3, but with items 10 through 19 in the XML file.
7. Continue until it reaches the end of the XML file.

**The skinny:** So basically, I need the script to create a main div, populate that main div with nine other divs (from an XML file), then repeat the process until it reaches the end of the list.

Is that possible?

Here's a sample of what the XML list would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<forms>
    <form>
        <name>Form 1</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form1</subjectCategory>
    </form>
    <form>
        <name>Form 2</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form2</subjectCategory>
    </form>
    <form>
        <name>Form 3</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form3</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 4</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form4</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 5</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form5</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 6</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form6</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 7</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form7</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 8</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form8</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 9</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form9</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 10</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form10</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 11</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form11</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 12</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form12</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 13</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form13</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 14</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form14</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 15</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form15</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 16</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form16</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 17</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form17</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 18</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form18</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 19</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form19</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 20</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form20</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 21</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form21</subjectCategory>
    </form> <form>
        <name>Form 22</name>
        <subjectCategory>Form22</subjectCategory>
    </form>
</forms>
```

Here's a script I started on, but it doesn't create new panel_wrap divs when needed. It just continues through the XML list until it reaches the end. I end up with a bunch of squares in one panel.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("form");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<div class='square'>");
  document.write("<p class='labels'>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>");
  document.write("</div>");
  }
```

Thanks to anyone who can help or point me in the right direction. I'm sorry this is a bit wordy. (I'm certainly a novice to this kind of work, though it's fun!)

Comment: You should really look at some on the existing templating libraries, such as underscore.js.

Comment: As @Diodeus suggested, libraries and frameworks might be better. I would suggest you looking at Angular. Also, why XML? JSON is easier to parse and use from the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Diodeus. I'll poke around underscore.js, but I'm afraid I won't be able to recognize a solution if I saw it. Would you be kind enough to provide some search terms, or perhaps help me re-phrase my question so it makes more sense? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with help from a friend, I accomplished what I needed to do. (Though there's still a bit more tweaking, this gives me the basic structure I needed.)

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","forms.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var j=0;
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("form");
panel = x.length/9;

console.log(panel);

for (h=0;h<panel;h++){
  document.write("<div class='panel_wrap' id='ius'>");
  document.write("<div class='previous' id='nav'>");
  document.write("</div>");
  document.write("<div class='next' id='nav'>");
  document.write("<a href='#ius2'></a>");
  document.write("</div>");

  for (i=0;i<9;i++)
    { 
    document.write("<div class='square'>");
    document.write("<p class='labels'>");
    document.write(x[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>");
    document.write("</div>");
    j++;
    }
  document.write("</div>");
  }
</script>
```